# grep output in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

why does grep in a script run in Cygwin not maintain columnar output from a text file when it's (grep's) output is redirected to another text file - say a list of x, y coordinates marked by x and y which it can separate to 2 files (one of x coords and the other of y coords with the xs and ys being removable by sed).
Instead it outputs, what started as a column of numbers, as rows of space separated numbers?
I tried the Cygwin website but there's too much garbage to go through.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `grep`, when given two or more file name arguments, prepends the file name and a colon to each line.  If the columns are delimited by tabs, the tabstops aren't going to be in the same place.

The `-h` option inhibits the filename prefix, and should avoid any misalignment, since `grep` doesn't modify its input lines (other than by prepending the file name).

You can also consider filtering the input files with `expand` to replace tabs with spaces.

If that doesn't solve the problem, please post some sample input and output.